# ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection with optional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In an ASP.NET Core 1.0 I'm trying to inject to `BaseRepository` constuctor two parametrs. One is SwitchContext (registered below, and custom parametr - RepositoryCacheMode (just enum))

I there is way to register parameter like this?

```
services.AddTransient<RepositoryCacheMode, RepositoryCacheMode.None>();
```

or how to get instance of SwitchContext for reginstration of BaseRepository?

```
public static void AddDependency(this IServiceCollection services)
        {                  
            services.AddTransient<SwitchContext, SwitchContext>();
            services.AddTransient<IRepository, BaseRepository>(t => new BaseRepository(// How to get instanse of SwitchContext ? // , RepositoryCacheMode.None));
```

Constructor of BaseRepository:

```
  public BaseRepository(SwitchContext context, RepositoryCacheMode cacheMode = RepositoryCacheMode.FirstLevel)
        {
            Context = context;
            _cacheMode = cacheMode;
        }
```

Comment: I Flagged you as duplicate because it looks like almost the exact same question. The only difference is that you use defaults, and he wants default null. both ways don't work and its explained there why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `t` is the `ServiceProvider` so you can just do:

```
services.AddTransient<IRepository, BaseRepository>(
    serviceProvider => new BaseRepository(serviceProvider.GetService<SwitchContext>())
);
```

Comment: well, it works for me but I was not able to find Resolve method and I used (r=>r. GetService<SwitchContext>())

Comment: @Ilya.Sulimanov ah yes sorry, i was used to the old Unity container. i changed the answer